# I am not a balloon. What am I?

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

*My inner part is filled with helium*
*Rubber comprises my epithelium*
*If you tie me 'bout your hand*
*Then I'll stay closer to the ground*
*Else I'll go up to the sky*
*I am not a balloon, what am I?*

Comment: is it an inflate blimps?

Comment: @H.Modh I think the answer is more 'out of the box'.

Comment: To improve the rhyme, you could change the third line to "If I to your hand am bound".  :-)

Comment: @Hellion If my current idea about this riddle is correct, the answer is probably "no".

Comment: A helium filled condom. Or just a bloke wearing one.

Comment: I came up with this last night at 3am when I couldn't stay asleep. The intended answer was " a balloon that tells lies"

Comment: is anyone else sick of all these "oh, just kidding, I was lying" riddles?

Comment: What, really? **REALLY?** Man I thought about this all yesterday and wasted hours on research and brainstorming. And now my upvote is locked when I really just want to downvote this. I guess I've learned my lesson about upvoting questions here before I know the answer. I'm pretty sure I got here from the Hot Network Questions list, it has 1K views and it's not even a real riddle! What's next, "What have I got in my pocket?"

Comment: @ToddWilcox why should it matter what the author's intent was? There is a really good answer, so we can all just agree that is the correct answer, and from that point of view it is still an excellent riddle. We should also thank "Clint Eastwood" for his honesty, he could easily have pretended that he was going for dmg's answer all along. (With that said, Clint, please don't do that again...)

Comment: @BigBlackBox While dmg's answer is likely to be the best one possible, it does not satisfy what to me is the core purpose of a riddle, which is that it's something that seems so obvious once you actually know the answer. dmg's answer doesn't really seem *right*. Only the helium and rubber parts of it work very well. As frustrating as this "riddle" is, "A balloon that lies" is a better answer than dmg's based on my criteria.

Comment: Wait, so "a balloon that lies" is the answer? At least put that as an answer and mark this solved..

Comment: How about "a balloon with an identity crisis"?  (Everything it said was true except the bit about not being a balloon)

Comment: @Raystafarian That would be a very bad idea. [This](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10466/the-traveler-and-the-blood-thirsty-troll/10508#10508) is what happened when a terrible answer to a question was accepted.

Comment: @dperry I asked a [Meta question](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4494/what-is-the-sites-stand-on-unsatisfying-riddles) about such riddles and how they should be handled.

Comment: I am satisfied with dmgs answer. And am amused over how many pts i lost when I revealed my original deranged intentions.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Is it a

> Portable hard drive

*My inner part is filled with helium*

> Some hard drives are filled with helium to reduce internal friction

*Rubber comprises my epithelium*

> Rubberized to prevent damage if it falls

*If you tie me 'bout your hand*
*Then I'll stay closer to the ground*

> If you connect it to your PC it will be relatively close to the ground and at the tip of your fingers. Alternatively "grounding" the hard drive (credits to [Adam Davis](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/1682/adam-davis)) or wearing a grounding wristband (credits to [Dane Andersen](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/17057/dane-andersen)).

*Else I'll go up to the sky*

> Alternatively you can store all your data in the "cloud"

*I am not a balloon, what am I?*

> A hard drive

Comment: nice one...!! @dmg

Comment: *"Closer to the ground"* might have more to do with electrically grounding the hard drive when connected to the computer than being physically close to ground.

Comment: @AdamDavis I thought that that might also be a possible explanation, along with "grounding" oneself before touching the PC, but kinda liked the literal "closer to the ground".

Comment: Some people use a grounding strap that you literally tie around your hand (wrist) to keep you grounded while working with electronics.

Comment: @DaneAndersen Nice catch

Comment: I don't know about this seems like a bit of a stretch, "else I'll go up to the sky" the cloud has little to do with a personal hard drive, and I know you say it's an alternative but there are plenty of alternatives to the cloud for your data. And the hard drive itself isn't going to the sky anyway the data is.

Comment: Yes, I also don't like that "Else I'll go up to the sky" => [Alternatively you can store all your data in the "cloud"]- in this case, 'you' is being 'user' where it should be 'hard drive' according to your answer. Hard drive can't go up to the sky.

Comment: "You" is user in the entire answer.

Answer (score 9):

I think it is a

> laser barcode scanner.

*My inner part is filled with helium*

> Laser barcode scanners contain [helium-neon lasers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helium%E2%80%93neon_laser).

*Rubber comprises my epithelium*

> The scanners have an external enclosure made of rubber.

*If you tie me 'bout your hand

Then I'll stay closer to the ground*

> When one holds the scanner in their hand, it is aimed at the items in the checkout counter (closer to the ground)

*Else I'll go up to the sky*

> When the scanner is left on the rack, the beam will point upwards towards the sky.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is

> Lightweight aircraft

My inner part is filled with helium

> Helium is used as a fuel ([Reference](http://www.usesof.net/uses-of-helium.html))

Rubber comprises my epithelium

> We have rubber band powered airplanes.([Reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WcwK-pPOP54))

If you tie me 'bout your hand
Then I'll stay closer to the ground

> If you have it in hand. It won't go up.

Else I'll go up to the sky

> Possible reference to leave it after adding potential energy in it.

Comment: Helium is almost completely inert, and cannot be used as a fuel. It won't take part in any chemical reactions. The site you linked to is simply wrong -- they may have been confused by a proposal to use helium to reduce the weight of light aircraft and reduce fuel _use_.

Comment: @MikeScott Nice interpretation. Then i think we can use it as thruster.

Comment: @MikeScott +1, but If you stretch the "fuel" idea to the limit, it can be plausibly used as a fusion fuel in the [triple alpha chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple-alpha_process).

Comment: @MarchHo Got any examples of light aircraft powered by triple-alpha fusion?

Comment: @MikeScott I might have forgotten to end it with /sarcasm.

Comment: @MikeScott They seem to confuse hydrogen and helium several times.